# Windows Overwriting console

Tags: console, mingw

I was downloading MingW, and noticed that for a time the installer spawns a console window and downloads files. The intersting part is that it somehow creates download bars in the console window and overwrites the precentage number. I was wondering how this is accomplished?

NOTE:I am almost 100% sure the console is not writing `'\n'` out and is in fact overwriting the console.

Answer (score 0):

I see Google was broken.

http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=1499

The code:

```
@echo off
:: *****************************************************************************
:: * Script Name: DetectMSI_v1.0.cmd                                           *
:: * Author: Gustaaf von Pickartz.                                             *
:: * Date Created: 19th July, 2012.                                            *
:: * Internal Version: Version 1.0                                             *
:: * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- *
:: * Notice:                                                                   *
:: * This program is provided as is and for fair use distribution.             *
:: * Give credit where credit is due to the author in your own script.         *
:: * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- *
:: * Purpose:                                                                  *
:: * Detect current active MSIEXEC instances using a function for repeatable   *
:: * calls within a script and display a progress bar...                       *
:: * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- *
:: * Updated by: -------                                                       *
:: * Date: 19-07-2012                                                          *
:: * Change1: "Initial script version."                                        *
:: * ------------------------------------------------------------------------- *
:: *****************************************************************************
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

 SET PRG0=[*         ]
 SET PRG1=[#*        ]
 SET PRG2=[##*       ]
 SET PRG3=[###*      ]
 SET PRG4=[####*     ]
 SET PRG5=[#####*    ]
 SET PRG6=[######*   ]
 SET PRG7=[#######*  ]
 SET PRG8=[########* ]
 SET PRG9=[#########*]
SET PRG10=[##########]
:: Please note there are special ASCII insertions in the SET BKSPC= declaration below. 80x backspace characters are inserted. ASCII Value 08=[BS]
:: Be sure to verify they are still there when you cut and paste from the web with your text editor (Notepad++ or PsPad). Insert them if missing, otherwise this script will not work...
SET BKSPC=

:Begin_Main
  :: For the sake of the demonstration, start MSIEXEC minimized.
  START /MIN MSIEXEC

  :: Call our function.
  CALL :Fnc_Msi

  :: Waste a little time...  
  PING -n 7 localhost >nul  
  ECHO Exited the FIRST MSIEXEC detection function and progress bar demo.
  ECHO.
  ECHO.
  ECHO A function can't be a function if it cannot be re-used right?

  :: For the sake of the demonstration, start MSIEXEC minimized.
  START /MIN MSIEXEC

  :: Call our function.
  CALL :Fnc_Msi  
  ECHO Exited the SECOND MSIEXEC detection function and progress bar demo.
  echo.
  echo.
  pause
  GOTO :EOF
:: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

:: Below code is setup to run as a Function to be called anywhere in your script.
:: It will wait 10 loops at 7 sec intervals anytime it is called. Primarily written to detect active MSI installers.
:: The Menu counter and Progress bar is in the function for fun.
::
:: Usage: CALL :Fnc_Msi
2
:Fnc_Msi
       CALL ECHO [.....] %%date%% %%time%% Testing for active MSI instances.

       :catchit
       IF NOT DEFINED CatchMSI SET CatchMSI=0
       IF %CatchMSI% EQU 5 (
          ECHO Waited 5 loops {15sec.} to detect MSI activities. Now resuming further MSI evaluation.
          goto evalmsi
        )
       FOR /F "TOKENS=2* DELIMS=:" %%I IN ('TASKLIST /V /FI "IMAGENAME EQ MSIEXEC.EXE" /FO LIST 2^>NUL ^|FIND /I /V "N/A" ^|FIND /I "WINDOW TITLE:"') DO (SET MSI=%%I)
       IF DEFINED MSI SET MSI_APP=%MSI:~1%
       IF DEFINED MSI_APP goto msi_active
       >NUL PING -n 3 localhost
       SET /A CatchMSI+=1
       goto :catchit

       :evalmsi
       IF NOT DEFINED MSI_APP (
          ECHO [OKAY.] No active MSIEXEC installer running. It is safe to continue.
          SET CatchMSI=
          SET MSI_APP=
          SET CNT=
          SET COUNT=
          SET TIC=
          GOTO :EOF
        )

       :msi_active
       SET CNT=0
       ECHO [ALERT] Installer "%MSI_APP%" is active. Waiting maximum 10 counts.

       :loop
       IF NOT DEFINED COUNT SET COUNT=0
       IF %COUNT% LEQ 9 (SET TIC=0%COUNT%) ELSE (SET TIC=%COUNT%)
       IF %count% EQU 10 (
          <NUL (SET/P Z=[%tic%/10] PROGRESS: !PRG%CNT%!)
          :: Feel free to adjust the PING -n 3 value to say 30sec waits. 
          >NUL PING -n 3 localhost
          TASKKILL /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq %MSI_APP%*" >>myprogress.log
          <NUL SET/P Z=%BKSPC%
          SET MSI_APP=
          SET CatchMSI=
          SET MSI_APP=
          SET CNT=
          SET COUNT=
          SET TIC=
          GOTO :EOF
        )
        <NUL (SET/P Z=[%tic%/10] PROGRESS: !PRG%CNT%!)
        :: Feel free to adjust the PING -n 3 value to say 30sec waits. 
        >NUL PING -n 3 localhost
        <NUL SET/P Z=%BKSPC%
          :: Here we write to a log file and call tasklist.exe to do interval checks on the MSIEXEC status.
          :: Demonstrated is that the progress bar is not affected when code is run in the loop. 
          :: Do keep in mind to "suppress to >nul 2>nul" any output that may disrupt the progress bar activty.
          ECHO [%tic%/10] Waiting for "%MSI_APP%" to complete. >>myprogress.log
          TASKLIST.EXE /V | FIND /I "%MSI_APP%">NUL 2>NUL
          IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (
             >NUL PING -n 7 localhost
             SET CatchMSI=
             SET MSI_APP=
             SET CNT=
             SET COUNT=
             SET TIC=
             GOTO :EOF
           )
           SET /A CNT+=1
           SET /A COUNT+=1
       goto loop
GOTO :EOF
:: -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Credit is obviously due to the original author.